# Is ${\frac{d }{dt}}_{|t=0} ae^{tX}=a{\frac{d }{dt}}_{|t=0} e^{tX} $?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a lie group. Let $a\in G$, we consider the map $L_a: G \rightarrow G$, $g \longmapsto ag $. I want to explicit the derivative of $L_a$ at $e \in G$, but I get confused. More precisely:

Let $X = {\frac{d }{dt}}_{|t=0} e^{tX}\in T_e(G)$, then $dL_a(X)= {\frac{d }{dt}}_{|t=0}L_a( e^{tX})= {\frac{d }{dt}}_{|t=0} ae^{tX}$. How do we continue from here, does ${\frac{d }{dt}}_{|t=0} ae^{tX}=a{\frac{d }{dt}}_{|t=0} e^{tX} $ ?

I realize from this problem that I don't understand what is the definition ${\frac{d }{dt}} f(t)$, if $f(t)$ lies in a lie group. If $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we know that ${\frac{d }{dt}}_{|t=0} f(t) = lim_{t \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(t)-f(0) }{t}}$, but what is it's definition in a context of a Lie group.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you define tangent vectors to curves lying in a manifold? And, to your second point, can you multiply a Lie group element by a tangent vector to the Lie group? There's a reason you write $dL_a$ and not $a$. You might start by understanding left multiplication and its derivative in the setting of a *matrix* Lie group. You need to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

The reason we write $\frac{d}{dt}\mid_{t=0}$ on a Lie group is because the definition is exactly the same as it is for a function on the real line. Note that our function is a function from a Lie group to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so adding two function values and dividing by $t$ is defined just as usual.

Comment: if $f(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\mid_{t=0}e^{tX} $ , I don't understand how can we apply the usual definition because we don't have the operation of addition,  so the difference  $e^{tX} -e^{t0}$ is not defined.